# inequality Is the correct way?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Is the correct way?
Is that way solving exercise or it's not the right way I will be happy to explain
thank you!!!!!

[image: enter image]

Answer (score 2):

$$9x^3+30x^2+28x+8\ge0$$
$$(x+2)(3x+2)^2\ge0$$
$$x\ge-2$$

Comment: I think you left out $x=-2/3$.

Comment: @zxcvber not really. $(3x + 2)^2 \geq 0$ $\forall$ $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so you only need to care about $(x + 2) \geq 0$.